# Logstash-5.x.x - Could not be started; but Logstash-2.x.x is working fine

Tags: logging, log4j, logstash

Downloaded Logstash-5.1.2 and Logstash-5.2.1 tar.gz files from the official site and extracted it in my linux machine. But when i try to run it using the following basic command

```
bin/logstash -e 'input { stdin { } } output { stdout {} }'
```

I am getting the following error
[java/lang/ClassLoader.java:-2:in `defineClass1': java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.YamlLayout cannot access its superclass org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.AbstractJacksonLayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjZLq.jpg)

But the same command is working fine for Logstash-2.x.x version. 
Can anybody help me out on this. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

logstash 5.x requires java 8 to run. logstash 2.x will require java 7 or later. Check and upgrade your java version. `java -version`

Comment: Hi Ravi. Thank you for your response. But i am already using the Java 8 version. 
The details of "java -version" are below : 
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)

Comment: paste output of this command `update-java-alternatives --list`

Comment: Hi Ravi. 
i could not use the command that you mentioned. it is getting returned as "bash: update-java-alternatives: command not found..."
Please note that i am using Cent OS 7